# Haskell: filtering a heterogenous list by type

Tags: haskell, filter

We can use pair sequences to create heterogenous lists in Haskell:

```
type a *: b = (a, b)
a *: b = (a, b)
infixr 5 *:

hlist :: Int *: String *: Maybe Float *: ()
hlist = 1 *: "hello" *: Just 3 *: () -- (1, ("hello", (Just 3, ())))
```

Is there a way we can do type-level filtering on these lists?  That is, define some polymorphic function `hfilter` such that for distinct types `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
hfilter :: a *: b *: c *: a *: b *: a *: () ->  a *: a *: a *: ()
hfilter :: a *: b *: c *: a *: b *: a *: () ->  b *: b *: ()
hfilter :: a *: b *: c *: a *: b *: a *: () ->  c *: ()
hfilter :: a *: b *: c *: a *: b *: a *: () ->  ()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's possible with a few type extensions (as an aside, please check that your example code compiles when posting questions. I had to make quite a few corrections).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}

type a :* b = (a, b)
a *: b = (a, b)
infixr 5 *:
infixr 5 :*

hlist :: Int :* String :* Int :* Maybe Float :* ()
hlist = 1 *: "hello" *: 2 *: Just 3 *: ()


class TypeFilter lst t where
    hfilter :: lst -> [t]

instance TypeFilter () t where
    hfilter _ = []

instance TypeFilter rest t => TypeFilter (t :* rest) t where
    hfilter (a, rest) = a : hfilter rest

instance TypeFilter rest t => TypeFilter (a :* rest) t where
    hfilter (_, rest) = hfilter rest
```

Now we can filter items by type by explicitly defining the type of the list we want.

```
*Main> hfilter hlist :: [Int]
[1,2]
*Main> hfilter hlist :: [String]
["hello"]
*Main> hfilter hlist :: [Maybe Float]
[Just 3.0]
*Main> hfilter hlist :: [Maybe Int]
[]
```

It works by defining a multi-parameter type-class `TypeFilter`, which takes the type of the heterogenous list and the type we want to filter by. We then define instances for the empty list/unit `()` and for a list where the type matches (`TypeFilter (t :* rest) t`) and finally for a list where the type of the head is different than the type we want to retrieve (`TypeFilter (a :* rest) t)`.

Note that in the last instance there is currently no way to signify that `a` and `t` must be different types, but when they are the same [`OverlappingInstances`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap) counts the instance `TypeFilter (t :* rest) t` as more specific and chooses it over the `TypeFilter (a :* rest) t` one.

Comment: Sorry about the compilation problems, I was posting from my phone.

Comment: Ok, I was able to get from this to [a version that doesn't require `OverlappingInstances` by passing a filter argument](https://gist.github.com/1885439) `hfilter :: a -> h -> h'`, and that uses heterogenous lists for the output.  So `hfilter (undefined :: Int) hlist :: ()` is `()`, `hfilter (undefined :: Int) hlist :: Int :* ()` is `1 :* ()` and `hfilter (undefined :: Int) hlist :: Int :* Int :* ()` is `1 :* 2 :* ()`.

Comment: arg, but that requires `OverlappingInstances` to actually use.

Answer (score 2):

Although there exist methods to do what you ask, there is a very high probability that you are not playing Haskell strength here. Could you elaborate on your needs ? Usually you can enumerate all variants that you will need in an algebraic data type. Your list will then be homogeneous, allowing you to pattern-match on elements to operate on it.

Comment: Using an ADT, you'd probably end up with a solution similar in spirit to [`catMaybes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes), which filters the list by a particular constructor.

Comment: I'm playing with writing a stack-based DSL (somewhat resembling factor) in haskell - the heterogenous list in this case is the stack.

Comment: ah, I think I see, maybe something in the spirit of Sami's SNOC-pair based polymorphic stack [described here](https://github.com/leonidas/codeblog/blob/master/2012/2012-02-17-concatenative-haskell.md) ?